# Spring Boot & Docker using VOLUME /tmp

Tags: docker, spring-boot

Is anyone able to explain why the [Spring Boot Docker Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512035000/https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_containerize_it) recommends adding the `/tmp` volume as follows:

```
VOLUME /tmp
```

It explains:

> We added a VOLUME pointing to "/tmp" because that is where a Spring Boot application creates working directories for Tomcat by default. The effect is to create a temporary file on your host under "/var/lib/docker" and link it to the container under "/tmp".

however, I'm not really clear why you'd want/need to do this.

If the java application creates any files in the /tmp directory of the container I don't see what the need is to configure this as a volume since, as far as I understand, it would result in files bypassing the union filesystem and being written persistently in the Docker host to `/var/lib/docker`. Could this also result in the "temporary" files created in the container not being automatically deleted when the container is stopped?

My spring boot app (which does create temporary files) seems to run ok without this `VOLUME`, but I wonder if there are any negative consequences to not following this advice.

Thanks.

Comment: "Could this also result in the "temporary" files created in the container not being automatically deleted when the container is stopped?" — Only if you forget to use the `-v` option when deleting the container.

Comment: disk performances on volumes is better than on the docker container layered filesystem. That's why you don't want to make disk intensive operations on the docker filesystem

Comment: It is also worth asking what about the situation where you run multiple Spring Boot containers on the same host. Do they share these working directories? Should they?

Comment: @dominikbrandon When you run multiple Spring Boot containers, each containers will have its own dedicated volume on host filesystem, although they mount the same /tmp volume. In case you want them to shared the same volume, that's a different story.

Answer (score 6):

As said in the comments, because of the union file system, writing in the container is probably slower than writing in a volume.

Also, if you want to be able to reuse temporary files between container restart, using a volume is necessary but if this is not the case it would be probably better to use a tmpfs mount as described in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/).

Answer (score 1):

I have learned it the hard way. This is very essential when running the container as a non root user. In fact its a must.

Comment: Can you explain why it's a must?

Comment: @UroshT. when running as a non-root user, the /tmp directory will have no access, if not defined as a Volume. But in order to work, you need an access to the /tmp directory. Which makes it a mandate. As any file IO is done in this directory.